# RMarkdown Pandoc Error when my pandoc version is 2.3.1

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc, rstudio-server, r-server

I'm trying to knitr a Rmd file on Rserver via command line by running

```
Rscript -e "rmarkdown::render('testrmd.Rmd')"
```

But it ran into an error saying

```
"Error: pandoc version 1.12.3 or higher is required and was not found (see the help page ?rmarkdown::pandoc_available).
```

Execution halted"

However, I checked and found out that I actually have pandoc version 2.3.1, way higher than the required 1.12.3.

[image]

Comment: I was testing it with the default RMarkdown files with "summary(cars)" stuff. And the file knits perfectly when I click the knit button.

Comment: RStudio uses an own version of pandoc shipped with RStudio. You can download pandoc on mac via `homebrew`.